# How can I avoid deleting application data when Android Studio asks to reinstall app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-storage

I have an app which downloads a lot of data in the background and it is saved as Application data. So, when I'm debugging and sometimes Android Studio gives me this dialog:
[image]

And I want to avoid downloading all that application data(as it takes a lot of time). So what will be a possible solution or a hack to achieve it.

Comment: Are you running your device in an emulator? If so then increase storage size

Comment: it's a physical device (Samsung A9 tab 16GB) but it's loaded.

Comment: the app version is same so why it's asking to re-install?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is insufficient storge, you must have empty space in your device to install application, delete unused data,cache and other stuffs you don't need, maybe this will help you

Comment: OR Maybe this is happening due to instant run , you can disable instant run in your android studio setting then try to run the app

Comment: Instant run is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall other apps which you don't use. 
Delete photos/videos etc. 
Delete caches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a rooted physical device or an emulator. Access to files of the application from ''Device file explorer'' inside android studio And copy what you need before uninstalling  app.
Next time just recopy those files to the same emplecement in the device

Comment: doesn't need to be rooted device if it's your app.

Comment: The background jobs will start downloading data again.